# How do I operate with the width on a jQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I am creating a function that each time it is called 1px is subtracted to the width of an image. I can't figure it out...
Something like this:

```
var leafCompress = function(){
.css("width" -1 + "px");    //This line is definitely wrong
        }
```

(The following code is working) Here I'm adding the event listener so on each click it calls the leafCompress function.

```
leaf.on("click",function(){
           leafCompress();
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ex4Lh23v/

Answer (score 1):

the problem comes from your function leafCompress

```js
$( "#panda" ).on('click', () => {
    resize();
});


const resize = () => {
  let width = $("#panda").width() - 50; // get the width of the image and substract 50
   $("#panda").css("width", width);
}
```

```css
#panda {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="panda" src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_624/s_f/o_1/cx_0/cy_17/cw_624/ch_416/APL/uploads/2014/06/red-panda-09-625x350.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much man! I appreciate it, I couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using jQuery but, you can do it with jQuery .width function, 
the css('width') function returns the width as string i.e: "780px" and to use it to set the width property you usually do .css('width', valueToBeSet)

However you can achieve the same result using jQuery .width function
$().width() will return the actual width and $().width(value) will set width as the value

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial way:

```
leaf.click(function(){
    var node = $(this);
    node.css('width', node.width() - 1 + 'px');
})
```

If event handler is a function, "this" points to event target.